# How to fix PDF.JS throwing error "DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker'"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, pdf.js

I am trying to display a pdf in a custom web view in my xamarin.forms app.

The way the program works right now is this:
1. pdf is downloaded into a pdf directory on the phone
2. The pdf.js viewer.html is loaded into a custom web view using a custom renderer with ?file= set to http://localhost:8000/filepath
3. Errors are thrown

I have added http://localhost:8000 to the HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS in viewer.js and commented out the code that checks whether the viwer.html file and the pdf are from the same host as is suggested by my research. This eliminated most errors, but the error in the title persists.

The code to load the pdf into the viewer.html and that into the custom webview (found here: https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf):

```cs
var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
                Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                //, string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}"), WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri)
              Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("http://localhost:8000/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri))));
```

The slightly edited validateFileUrl method is this:

```js
var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io', 'http://localhost:8000'];

  validateFileURL = function validateFileURL(file) {
    if (file === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      var viewerOrigin = new _pdfjsLib.URL(window.location.href).origin || 'null';
      if (HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS.includes(viewerOrigin)) {
        return;
      }

      var _ref14 = new _pdfjsLib.URL(file, window.location.href),
          origin = _ref14.origin,
          protocol = _ref14.protocol;

      //if (origin !== viewerOrigin && protocol !== 'blob:') {
      //  throw new Error('file origin does not match viewer\'s');
      //}
    } catch (ex) {
      var message = ex && ex.message;
      PDFViewerApplication.l10n.get('loading_error', null, 'An error occurred while loading the PDF.').then(function (loadingErrorMessage) {
        PDFViewerApplication.error(loadingErrorMessage, { message: message });
      });
      throw ex;
    }
  };


In theory, the pdf should load into the pdf viewer. However, in practice, I get this error message:

"Uncaught (in promise) DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.js (13127)
[INFO:CONSOLE(985)] "Uncaught (in promise) Error: An error occurred while loading the PDF.", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.js (985)06-25 10:48:12.320 I/chromium( 9820): [INFO:CONSOLE(13127)] "Uncaught (in promise) DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.js (13127)

06-25 10:48:12.320 I/chromium( 9820): [INFO:CONSOLE(985)] "Uncaught (in promise) Error: An error occurred while loading the PDF.", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.js (985)
```

Comment: the link shows how to display a local PDF file in a WebView control ,are your current PDF files local (in asset folder)?

Comment: They are in the internal storage of the phone I'm testing on, hence the localhost.